# How to capture the screen through Cordova application?

Tags: android, cordova, webrtc, getusermedia, phonertc

Hi I tried below getUserMedia API to capture the android screen,But Its not working any help ?

```
const constraints = {
audio: false, // mandatory.
video: {'mandatory': {'chromeMediaSource':'screen'}}
};

const successCallback = (stream) => {
var video = document.querySelector('video');
video.srcObject = stream;
video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
video.play();
};
};
const errorCallback = (error) => {
// We don't have access to the API
console.log("sadd"+error);
 };
navigator.getUserMedia(constraints, successCallback, errorCallback);
```

I am getting the error Requested device not found

Comment: https://github.com/sebastiancesar/screen-recorder-cordova-plugin

Comment: Tried this but when I am calling this function ScreenRecorderPlugin.start, Then the application sends to the background and closes the instance, It's not like minimizing. Recording not starts

Comment: Also my requirement is i need to share my android screen to another web app

Comment: Does this help? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getDisplayMedia

Comment: @O.Jones No, it wont support WebView Android

Comment: Any update on this one? Anyway to stream the shared screen? Please help

Comment: This may help you https://github.com/dkrivoruchko/ScreenStream